# Get answer from local script

Tags: google-smart-home, ifttt, google-assistant

I am looking for a way to interact with my Google Home devices as follows:

> Me: When does the next bus arrive?
>
> Assistant: In 5 minutes.

My first thought was to scrape such data from the official public transport website from my city. But as I looked into the issue, this step can be skipped, as the time schedule is always the same and can be saved locally. Then it would only require to know the current time, to have the right answer.

The bigger problem here is, how can I let the google assistant answer the result. I looked into IFTTT, but I could not find any way to run some local function.
IFTTT or some other service would be the best solution, as it would not require any additional hardware to run.

Of course I would try some other solutions including additional hardware, if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interacting on a phone, you can build a simple phone app with this information and [use App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) to send the data to the Assistant.

For Google Homes, you cannot directly run logic locally on the hardware. What you can do is build a [conversational action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview) that sends out a request to [a webhook you control](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=sdk) which can easily respond back with the requested information.

Comment: Interaction with a phone would make my whole idea pointless, as you can lookup this information yourself. But the second solution you mentioned does look promising to me. Will try that. Thanks!